# Django query datetime by adding 5 hours 30 minutes to the original column

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm trying to write a Django query for orders that when added 5 hours 30 minutes satisfy the condition,created_at is datetime

```
SELECT id, created_at + time '5:30' as created_at , date(created_at + time '5:30') as created_date
          FROM orders WHERE date(created_at + time '5:30') > today_date
```

How to convert this into Django ORM ?

Comment: Why do you want to do this in first place? Is it because the records are stored with actual time +  5 hours 30 minutes?

Comment: yes,the records are stored in utc and i wanted to query in ist

Comment: Rather than adding using timezone module you can subtract 5 hours 30 minutes from current time(timezone.now()).So you can query it like this, Model.objects.filter(created_on__gte=(timezone.now() - timedelta(hours=5, minutes=30))). I have not tried it, but you can give it try and check if output is desirable.

Comment: Did the same thing, thanks for the hack

Answer (score 0):

I assume that TIME_ZONE in setting is set to 'Asia/Kolkata' (i.e. UTC+5:30). If you have this setting, you can use django's timezone module.

Let's say the model name in 'Order'. The above query will be like this in ORM form:

```
from django.utils import timezone
orders = Order.objects.filter(created_at__gt=timezone.now().date())
```

And to convert the date got from this query into your timezone:

```
order = orders.first()
created_at = timezone.localtime(order.created)
```

Comment: if i use the above, say  `Order.objects.filter(created_at__gt=timezone.now().date())`
wouldnt work as it is `created_at` is a datetime field, i am thinking to convert date to datetime then subtract to get utc, and then convert

Comment: Following should work: timezone.localtime(timezone.now()).date() instead of timezone.now().date()